# History of Renormalization Group

Tags: resource-recommendations, renormalization, history

I want to study from an historical point of view the renormalization group (starting from statistical mechanics). Are there any historical (but also technical) books about this? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that Goldenfeld's book may help you.